# app.config path error in winform application connected to access database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, app-config

I am very new to visual studio and i am building a data entry app in it using visual studio connected to Microsoft access database (VB.NET language).
But i am getting error during initial debug to check on the path like below:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: ''C:\Users\ramadasr\source\repos\Test2\bin\Debug\Database\Trialdatabase.accdb' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

And I have entered the app.config data correctly like below:

```xml
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database\Trialdatabase.accdb"
```

And actual folder location is this: `C:\Users\ramadasr\source\repos\Test2`

Please help me how to correct this , i have attached some images also for your reference.[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows a different exception "Could not find file". Does the file exist at that path?

Comment: Have you hard-coded the path of the dev machine instead of the storage path of the machine where the app is installed? See [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "Path")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.setdata)

Comment: Hi fixation.. there is a database but not where the exception message is showing..it is in "C:\Users\ramadasr\source\repos\Test2"  but in the exception it is showing the test2/bin folder extra

Comment: Hi Jimi...no I haven't done anything like that.all I want to know if my database is in "C:\Users\ramadasr\source\repos\Test2"..how to make changes in app config to make the code search there itself.

Comment: Is this path: `C:\Users\ramadasr\source\repos\Test2` referring to YOUR machine? When you deploy (install the executable(s) in another machine), you have to determine the path where you can store your editable components. Usually, in a subfolfer of the current User's `AppData` or in `ProgramData` (all Users). This *decision* can be part of the installation (with an Installer configured with these choices) or your executable, the first time it's run. I've already mentioned `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData()` (see what's that for).

Answer (score 1):

2 choices

- external location - keep your DB in a specific folder, like `c:\myDB`, This way, you just add this folder into your `app.config` and run with that
- relative location - add your db file as item of your project. Set in properties for this file - `Content` and `CopyAlways`. In the `app.config` have the relative path.
- Another variant - add DB file to your project as link from any location. And use same settings as #2

Comment: If I add my db in c ...after deployment can multiple users enter data to it through my forms?if yes..please elaborate the second step a bit more.

Comment: @RAVIKUMAR if app is used by multiple users then your DB must be sitting in some network drive. In this case, this is #1 only DB sits on the network drive